# How to access params in Go AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I'm using Go on AWS lambda and I'm writing the following code:

```
func HanldeLambdaFunction(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (Response, error) {
    limitString := request.QueryStringParameters["limit"]
    fmt.Println("limitString", limitString) //nothing is written
}
```

I'm testing the lambda function using the api gateway and providing params:

```
limit=2
```

The lambda function is being executed successfully but the limit is not being read.

How can I access the params?

Comment: How are you making the request to API Gateway? Pls include an example of the request + method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code you posted is, that it should not even compile. The biggest problem being, that there is no `Response` struct. It probably should be `events.APIGatewayProxyResponse`.

Furthermore, the code does not `return` anything, even though you define that it should return `Response` and `error`.

I took your code and fixed all of this and it works for me. The fixed code looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func HanldeLambdaFunction(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    limitString := request.QueryStringParameters["limit"]
    fmt.Println("limitString", limitString) //nothing is written

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{StatusCode: 200}, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HanldeLambdaFunction)
}
```

The output is:

```
START RequestId: 0c63f94f-b0aa-49de-ba6d-b1150d711b8a Version: $LATEST
limitString 2
END RequestId: 0c63f94f-b0aa-49de-ba6d-b1150d711b8a
REPORT RequestId: 0c63f94f-b0aa-49de-ba6d-b1150d711b8a  Duration: 0.56 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 34 MB
```

If I had to guess, then your code does not even run. If it would run but could not read the `limit` parameter, it should at least print `limitString`.

Remember, if you compile a go binary for AWS Lambda, you need to compile it for `linux` and `amd64` like so:

```
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

Comment: Thank you Jens, your answer is surely helpful, but that didn't work! I guess that the problem is in the API Gateway configuration. Thank you anyway!